# Calculate mean of levels interval

Tags: r, levels

I have levels that I wish to calculate the mean of. Do you have to use `gsub` and replace characters or are there another way?

```
# Reproduce data
x <- c("(-48.2,-47.8]", "(-61.9,-61.5]", "(-52.2,-51.8]", "(-43.7,-43.3]", "(-51.4,-51]", "(-43.3,-42.9]", "(-43.7,-43.3]", "(-47.4,-47]")

# I have data on the form as below
X <- as.factor(x)

# I want the mean of e.g X[1]
# mean(X[1]) = mean(-48.2 + -47.8)
```

Comment: what's it with the brackets opening with `(` and closing with `]`? and does your data really look like that and is not in some `data.frame` form?

Comment: Yes I used the `cut_interval()` function

Comment: Thank you for your suggested solutions, appreciated! I believe all has it's perks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try this approach using `dplyr()` to preserve all the numbers:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data.frame(x) %>% separate(x, into = c("num1", "num2"), sep = ",") %>%
  mutate(num1 = as.numeric(gsub("[()]|[][]", "", num1)),
         num2 = as.numeric(gsub("[()]|[][]", "", num2)),
         mean = (num1 + num2) / 2)
```

Output:

```
#    num1  num2  mean
# 1 -48.2 -47.8 -48.0
# 2 -61.9 -61.5 -61.7
# 3 -52.2 -51.8 -52.0
# 4 -43.7 -43.3 -43.5
# 5 -51.4 -51.0 -51.2
# 6 -43.3 -42.9 -43.1
# 7 -43.7 -43.3 -43.5
# 8 -47.4 -47.0 -47.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a three-step process of `gsub` (to remove what we don't want/need), `strsplit` (to separate the numbers by comma), and `mean(as.numeric(.))` (to actually calculate the numeric average) should work:

```r
gsub("[^-0-9.,]", "", x)
# [1] "-48.2,-47.8" "-61.9,-61.5" "-52.2,-51.8" "-43.7,-43.3" "-51.4,-51"   "-43.3,-42.9" "-43.7,-43.3" "-47.4,-47"  
strsplit(gsub("[^-0-9.,]", "", x), ",")
# [[1]]
# [1] "-48.2" "-47.8"
# [[2]]
# [1] "-61.9" "-61.5"
# [[3]]
# [1] "-52.2" "-51.8"
# [[4]]
# [1] "-43.7" "-43.3"
# [[5]]
# [1] "-51.4" "-51"  
# [[6]]
# [1] "-43.3" "-42.9"
# [[7]]
# [1] "-43.7" "-43.3"
# [[8]]
# [1] "-47.4" "-47"  
sapply(strsplit(gsub("[^-0-9.,]", "", x), ","), function(z) mean(as.numeric(z)))
# [1] -48.0 -61.7 -52.0 -43.5 -51.2 -43.1 -43.5 -47.2
```

(I should note that I'm interpreting your `mean(-48.2 + -47.8)` to really mean `mean(c(-48.2, -47.8))`, since otherwise `-48.2 + -47.8` seems not right.)

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Assuming that what is wanted is the mean of the two numbers in each component of `X`, remove the first and last character and read what is left using `read.table` creating a data frame in which each row is formed from one component of `X`.  Finally use `rowMeans` on that.

No packages are used.

```
rowMeans(read.table(text = sub(".(.*).", "\\1", X), sep = ","))
## [1] -48.0 -61.7 -52.0 -43.5 -51.2 -43.1 -43.5 -47.2
```

This can also be written as a pipeline:

```
X |> 
  sub(".(.*).", "\\1", x = _) |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = ",") |>
  rowMeans()
## [1] -48.0 -61.7 -52.0 -43.5 -51.2 -43.1 -43.5 -47.2
```

**1a)** A variation of this is the following that returns the result of read.table with the means as an extra column.

```
transform(read.table(text = sub(".(.*).", "\\1", X), sep = ","),
   mean = (V1 + V2) / 2)
##      V1    V2  mean
## 1 -48.2 -47.8 -48.0
## 2 -61.9 -61.5 -61.7
## 3 -52.2 -51.8 -52.0
## 4 -43.7 -43.3 -43.5
## 5 -51.4 -51.0 -51.2
## 6 -43.3 -42.9 -43.1
## 7 -43.7 -43.3 -43.5
## 8 -47.4 -47.0 -47.2
```

or as a pipeline:

```
X |> 
  sub(".(.*).", "\\1", x = _) |>
  read.table(text = _, sep = ",") |>
  transform(mean = (V1 + V2) / 2)
```

**2)** A similar approach using `strapply` also works.  This applies the indicated function, expressed using formula notation, to the capture groups.

```
library(gsubfn)

strapply(format(X), "^.(.*),(.*).$", ~ mean(as.numeric(c(x, y))), simplify = TRUE)
## [1] -48.0 -61.7 -52.0 -43.5 -51.2 -43.1 -43.5 -47.2
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
sapply(regmatches(x, gregexpr('[-0-9.]+', x)), \(x) mean(as.numeric(x)))

# [1] -48.0 -61.7 -52.0 -43.5 -51.2 -43.1 -43.5 -47.2
```